# bash -l /tmp/create_inputs returns connection refused in Rubber > Amazon EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

After 36 hours struggling with Amazon EC2 now I stuck with the following.

When Rubber reaches to run deploy-graylog.rb I get this error:

Here is the log from the last part of the execution:

```
** [out :: production.foo.com.au] graylog-web start/running, process 12772
    command finished in 750ms
    triggering after callbacks for `rubber:graylog:web:bootstrap'
  * 2014-02-21 22:01:24 executing `rubber:graylog:web:create_inputs'
    servers: ["production.foo.com.au"]
 ** sftp upload #<StringIO:0x007fb47410aec0> -> /tmp/create_inputs
    [production.foo.com.au] /tmp/create_inputs
    [production.foo.com.au] done
  * sftp upload complete
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: '  bash -l /tmp/create_inputs"
    servers: ["production.foo.com.au"]
    [production.foo.com.au] executing command
 ** [out :: production.foo.com.au] curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:12900; Connection refused
    command finished in 725ms
failed: "/bin/bash -l -c 'sudo -p '\\''sudo password: '\\''  bash -l /tmp/create_inputs'" on production.foo.com
```

When I SSH to the Server and run this `bash -l /tmp/create_inputs` directly I get the same error

Do I even need Graylog? if not how can I disable it?

Server is Ubuntu, m1.small
Ruby 2.0.0-p353
Rails 4.0.2

This is the /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
## rubber config production
10.248.163.48 production.foo.com.au production ec2-54-206-206-214.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com ip-10-248-163-48.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal elasticsearch-production.foo.com.au graphite-production.foo.com.au graylog-production.foo.com.au
## rubber config production
```

This is what in the /tmp/create_inputs

```
function error_exit { exit 99; }; trap error_exit ERR
          curl --user admin:admin1 -XPOST http://localhost:12900/system/inputs -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"type": "org.graylog2.inputs.gelf.udp.GELFUDPInput", "creator_user_id": "admin", "title": "gelf-udp", "global": true, "configuration": { "port": 12201, "bind_address": "0.0.0.0" } }'
          curl --user admin:admin1 -XPOST http://localhost:12900/system/inputs -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"type": "org.graylog2.inputs.syslog.udp.SyslogUDPInput", "creator_user_id": "admin", "title": "syslog-udp", "global": true, "configuration": { "port": 12514, "bind_address": "0.0.0.0" } }'
```

Thanks guys in advance

Comment: What's the content of `/tmp/create_inputs` on `production.foo.com.au` ? looks like it's just trying to connect to localhost:12900 . Is there anything supposed to be running there in your app ?

Comment: I have just added to the question. Thanks

Comment: What's running on 12900? looks like admin:admin1 is not allowed.

Comment: Hmm mm.  There was no port opened on the server by 12900. So I made it up on the ip table.  Now when I run the nmap I get that port 12900 is closed unknown reason. Even when I opened it as sudo still it is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone checked this.

At last I couldn't find any solution for it. Every time I tried I encountered a new problem so I gave up as clients are not going to pay if I can't deploy on the server properly :)

Now I am deploying my Rails App Manually via Git (Old School).
Since then I haven't had any issues.

Also I am using OpsWork which has been very helpful. I deploy different layers then add my Rails app to it at the end. I don't like BeanStalk and how it manages different layers so I stick with OpsWork or simply using an EC2 directly via the console.

Cheers

Comment: hmmm, I haven't had any issue with it. To be fair I used it once for a project, project is online and crunching numbers fine, and client haven't had any issue with the monitoring and working directly with the server (Or he hasn't told me anything :) ). These days, I configure everything regarding the server manually as I have got enough AMI to deploy different instances with different config. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing suggested above can be done this way. I believe this would be the better way to do it. Use `cap rubber:remove_role` command https://github.com/rubber/rubber/wiki/Commands .

1) `cap rubber:remove_role` -- prompts you for instance name say 'production'
2) then it asks you for roles --- Remove roles that you don't need. You can check them above in logs. Easy to copy and paste

Hope it helps! I got stuck with this for almost three days hoping to see my site live :( Will blog my experiences for sure.

Comment: I will run your solution and the other solution this week or early next week and will let you all know. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I couldn't figure out how to get Graylog working, but you can disable it in the following, slightly annoying way.

First, you have to destroy your existing instances. This is because you can't modify security groups on an existing ec2 instance.

```
cap rubber:destroy
```

Then, spin up new instances. I'm using staging, so for me it was:

```
cap rubber:create_staging
```

After you're asked what the app's name is (I used 'staging' instead of the default 'production', but I can't imagine this matters), you'll be asked which security groups you want in the app. **Don't accept the default**, but rather type out all the listed default security groups, **excluding** anything starting with graylog_.

For example:

```
apache,app,collectd,common,db:primary=true,elasticsearch,examples,graphite_server,graphite_web,haproxy,mongodb,monit,passenger,postgresql,postgresql_master,web,web_tools
```

Which is literally just re-typing (or copying) everything presented to you in the square brackets at that step, and deleting the graylog entries.

It's possible that there's another way to do this inside of a config, for instance using assigned_security_groups in the rubber.yml file, but I couldn't figure that out. This, although it requires me to type a long string every time I create an instance, seemed to be the quickest way to get this working.

Let me know if you figure out a way to either get graylog working with rubber or an easier way to disable graylog.

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: Thanks mate. I will have a go at this and will let you know. I need to run a new instance as I deployed the project instance from ground to the full mode from scratch. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I was tempted to do the same thing. Cheers.

Comment: have we found a solution to this in a nicer way? I've been comming back to copy/paste the security group to type for the past 2 days haha!

Answer (score 0):

The Same Problem.I guess the gray log  maybe not install/config property.
It's must be a bug.just remove this role templely.